# IllegalArgumentException on Container.add

Tags: java, awt

I created a program that will have 4 classes + a summary which will give the color, price, type, and options.
These classes are working fine but the main one is giving me some issues. And from the way the errors read it looks like I have added a window to a container or something but I am not seeing/understanding my mistakes.

This is my code for the main class:

```
public class VehiclePanelProgram extends JFrame
{
    VehicleColorPanel    vcp = new VehicleColorPanel();
    VehicleOptionsPanel  vop = new VehicleOptionsPanel(this);
    VehicleTypePanel     vtp = new VehicleTypePanel(this);
    VehiclePricePanel    vpp = new VehiclePricePanel();

    //It will show a summary of data from the other panels
    JPanel summaryPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton summaryButton = new JButton("Summary");

    public VehiclePanelProgram()
    {
        Container canvas = getContentPane();
        canvas.setLayout( new BorderLayout());

        canvas.add(vcp,BorderLayout.CENTER);//Line 23
        canvas.add(vop,BorderLayout.EAST);
        canvas.add(vpp,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        canvas.add(vtp,BorderLayout.WEST);

        fixUpSummaryPanel();
        canvas.add(summaryPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.setSize(600, 350);
        this.setTitle(" Vehicle Panel Program ");
        this.show();   
    }//End Program constructor

    public void fixUpSummaryPanel()
    {
        summaryPanel.setLayout( new FlowLayout());
        summaryPanel.add(summaryButton);

        summaryButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {

            }//End Action Constructor
        });//End ActionListener
    }//End SummaryPanel Constructor

    public void disableSunroof(){vop.disSunroof();}
    public void enableSunroof(){vop.enSunroof();}
    public void disableConvertible(){vtp.disCon();}
    public void enableConvertible(){vtp.enCon();}

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        VehiclePanelProgram app = new VehiclePanelProgram();//Line 58
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    }//End Main

}//End VehiclePanelProgram
```

And this is the output that I keep getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
    at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Container.java:488)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1089)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:971)
    at vehiclepanelprogram.VehiclePanelProgram.<init>(VehiclePanelProgram.java:23)
    at vehiclepanelprogram.VehiclePanelProgram.main(VehiclePanelProgram.java:58)
```

If needed I can provide you with my other classes.

Comment: where is the definition of `VehicleColorPanel` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I had to completely redo my code and when I did it all worked out.Thank you

Comment: maybe delete this question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your classes are inheriting from Window, which is a top level container, but you are trying to add it to another top level container (canvas). You are not allowed to do that.

Comment: ok I figured it I switched a few things around and I got it to work. Thank you.